# Ubuntu 18.04 software-properties-gtk failing with org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.ServiceUnknown

Tags: 18.04, xubuntu

Problem:

```
tim@ubuntu:~$ software-properties-gtk 
ERROR:dbus.proxies:Introspect error on :1.103:/: dbus.exceptions.DBusException: org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.NoReply: Message recipient disconnected from message bus without replying
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/software-properties-gtk", line 100, in <module>
    app = SoftwarePropertiesGtk(datadir=options.data_dir, options=options, file=file)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/softwareproperties/gtk/SoftwarePropertiesGtk.py", line 172, in __init__
    self.backend.Reload();
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/dbus/proxies.py", line 70, in __call__
    return self._proxy_method(*args, **keywords)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/dbus/proxies.py", line 145, in __call__
    **keywords)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/dbus/connection.py", line 651, in call_blocking
    message, timeout)
dbus.exceptions.DBusException: org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.ServiceUnknown: The name :1.103 was not provided by any .service files
tim@ubuntu:~$
```

The "name" value increments each time I try.

I have tried purging and reinstalling `dbus`
e.g.

```
 sudo aptitude reinstall apt apt-utils aptdaemon aptdaemon-data update-manager update-manager-core dbus
```

But to no avail.

This is a Xubuntu 18.04 install which until now has given no problems.

more info:

```
journalctl -e
```

gives the following output:

```
06 17:41:56 ubuntu earlyoom[810]: mem avail:  6439 of  7950 MiB (80 %), swap free: 3975 of 3975 MiB (100 %)
Sep 06 17:41:57 ubuntu dbus-daemon[723]: [system] Activating service name='com.ubuntu.SoftwareProperties' requested by ':1.97' (uid=1000 pid=5778 comm="/usr/bin/python3 /usr/bi
Sep 06 17:41:57 ubuntu com.ubuntu.SoftwareProperties[723]: Unable to init server: Could not connect: Connection refused
Sep 06 17:41:57 ubuntu com.ubuntu.SoftwareProperties[723]: Unable to init server: Could not connect: Connection refused
Sep 06 17:41:57 ubuntu dbus-daemon[723]: [system] Successfully activated service 'com.ubuntu.SoftwareProperties'
Sep 06 17:41:57 ubuntu com.ubuntu.SoftwareProperties[723]: Traceback (most recent call last):
Sep 06 17:41:57 ubuntu com.ubuntu.SoftwareProperties[723]:   File "/usr/lib/software-properties/software-properties-dbus", line 68, in <module>
Sep 06 17:41:57 ubuntu com.ubuntu.SoftwareProperties[723]:     server = SoftwarePropertiesDBus(bus, datadir=datadir)
Sep 06 17:41:57 ubuntu com.ubuntu.SoftwareProperties[723]:   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/softwareproperties/dbus/SoftwarePropertiesDBus.py", line 66, in __init__
Sep 06 17:41:57 ubuntu com.ubuntu.SoftwareProperties[723]:     self._livepatch_service = LivepatchService()
Sep 06 17:41:57 ubuntu com.ubuntu.SoftwareProperties[723]:   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/softwareproperties/LivepatchService.py", line 93, in __init__
Sep 06 17:41:57 ubuntu com.ubuntu.SoftwareProperties[723]:     self._session = requests_unixsocket.Session()
Sep 06 17:41:57 ubuntu com.ubuntu.SoftwareProperties[723]: NameError: name 'requests_unixsocket' is not defined
```

Answer (score 3):

It turns out that import requests_unixsocket was failing in /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/softwareproperties/LivepatchService.py because

```
 try:
     import dateutil.parser
     import requests_unixsocket

     gi.require_version('Snapd', '1')
     from gi.repository import Snapd
 except(ImportError, ValueError):
     pass
```

and it was dateutil.parser not importing with an error that module six was not present.
The package python3-six was installed (so my package manager said).
when I reinstalled this package, software-properties-gtk worked again.

Comment: I have the [same error](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1271611/app-software-updates-not-responding) in Ubuntu 18.04. I tried your answer but the error still persists.

Comment: I had similar, but simply dateutil wasn't working, fixed it with `sudo apt install python3-dateutil --reinstall`

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue. This did the trick:

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install --reinstall python3-six python3-certifi
```

Comment: yayyy this worked for me <3

Answer (score 1):

For me it worked by reinstalling `python3-urllib3`:

```
sudo apt install --reinstall python3-urllib3
```

Also I suggest to update `python3-six`, `python3-certifi` and `python3-requests`.

Answer (score 0):

Similar to the other answers, I had a bunch of python modules whose versions I'd updated using pip (for some scripts I was testing), which then broke software-properties-gtk, but on Ubuntu 20.04 LTS.

I removed those versions and reinstalled them via apt.

```
sudo pip uninstall six certifi urllib3 dateutil requests

sudo apt install --reinstall \
    python3-six \
    python3-certifi \
    python3-urllib3 \
    python3-dateutil \
    python3-requests \
    software-properties-gtk
```

I now use virtual python environments (via Anaconda) so this doesn't happen again.

Reference for software-properties-gtk dependencies: https://reposcope.com/package/software-properties-gtk/dependencies

Answer (score -1):

```
sudo apt purge software-properties-gtk
sudo apt autoremove
sudo apt update
sudo apt install software-properties-gtk
sudo software-properties-gtk
```

I had same problem and i reinstall software-properties-gtk and my problem fixed

Comment: Unfortunately, this answer did not solve my issue either.

Comment: what error you got same as this post or its something else?

Comment: Same as this post. You can see it [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1271611/app-software-updates-not-responding).