# Software & Updates doesn't open in 20.04 LTS

Tags: software-installation, 20.04

I cannot open Software & Updates, either by going to Activities, and clicking on the Software & Updates icon, or trying to open it from the terminal with the command:

```
software-properties-gtk
```

I have also tried reinstalling:

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall software-properties-gtk
```

After the re-installation, it either doesn't open, or, if it does, it just shows an empty white screen.  What is the problem here?

I am running Ubuntu 20.04.

Comment: If you get any error or warning messages when trying to launch it in terminal, please edit your question and show us.

Comment: @GunnarHjalmarsson, no I do not.

Comment: Run `sudo journalctl -f`, then launch it. Wait a minute without doing anything else, then exit. Ctrl + C to stop the journalctl, then add the output to your post. It might help, with luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've figured it out!  Apparently, I needed to run the `software-properties-gtk` command with root privileges, like

```
sudo software-properties-gtk
```

And now everything works just fine.  Also running `

```
sudo journalctl -f
```

and then launching the app worked well too.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem and `sudo software-properties-gtk` did not solve it.

However, as suggested by [this answer in Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/a/1281228/1131911) the following command solved it:

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install --reinstall python3-six python3-certifi
```

Answer (score 0):

For me, this stopped working when I changed the `update-alternatives --config python3` to python 3.7 from the system installed python 3.8.

Changing this back via the command above and instantly I was able to launch software updates.