# App “Software & Updates” not responding

Tags: 18.04, software-sources

I can't seem to get “Software & Updates” Application to appear after clicking on it. I don't know why. It's icon appears in the shortcut. What is the terminal command to activate this App?

I have tried this answer: [“Software Updater” & “Software & Updates” not working](https://askubuntu.com/a/556045/541417), but it did not work.

```
$ uname -a
Linux Ubuntu 5.4.0-42-generic #46~18.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Fri Jul 10 07:21:24 UTC 2020 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

$ gnome-shell --version
GNOME Shell 3.28.4

$ software-properties-gtk
ERROR:dbus.proxies:Introspect error on :1.228:/: dbus.exceptions.DBusException: org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.NoReply: Message recipient disconnected from message bus without replying
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/software-properties-gtk", line 100, in <module>
    app = SoftwarePropertiesGtk(datadir=options.data_dir, options=options, file=file)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/softwareproperties/gtk/SoftwarePropertiesGtk.py", line 173, in __init__
    self.backend.Reload();
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/dbus/proxies.py", line 70, in __call__
    return self._proxy_method(*args, **keywords)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/dbus/proxies.py", line 145, in __call__
    **keywords)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/dbus/connection.py", line 651, in call_blocking
    message, timeout)
dbus.exceptions.DBusException: org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.ServiceUnknown: The name :1.228 was not provided by any .service files
```

I also have the same msgs as in [Ubuntu 18.04 software-properties-gtk failing with org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.ServiceUnknown](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1171211/ubuntu-18-04-software-properties-gtk-failing-with-org-freedesktop-dbus-error-ser). I used Synaptic to reinstall the package `python3-size` as was mentioned in this [answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1171255/541417) but to no avail.

I had also tried purging and reinstalling `software-properties-gtk` as was mentioned [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/1178972/541417) but to no avail.

**Update1:**

I wonder if `setuptools.py` ver 50.0 broke software-properties-gtk's connection? I know that the system had this upgraded yesterday from ver 42.0.2. I just found this GitHub issue "[setuptools 50 breaks pip installation](https://github.com/pypa/setuptools/issues/2350)" which was raised 22 hours ago. I have uninstalled it but to no avail.

**Update 2:**
Using `journalctl -e` cmd in the terminal, I found this error msg:

```
Oct 04 08:22:14 Prime dbus-daemon[1303]: [system] Activating service name='com.ubuntu.SoftwareProperties' requested by ':1.157' (uid=1000 pid=10808 comm="/usr/bin/python3 /usr/bin/soft
Oct 04 08:22:14 Prime com.ubuntu.SoftwareProperties[1303]: Unable to init server: Could not connect: Connection refused
Oct 04 08:22:14 Prime com.ubuntu.SoftwareProperties[1303]: Unable to init server: Could not connect: Connection refused
Oct 04 08:22:14 Prime dbus-daemon[1303]: [system] Successfully activated service 'com.ubuntu.SoftwareProperties'
Oct 04 08:22:14 Prime com.ubuntu.SoftwareProperties[1303]: Traceback (most recent call last):
Oct 04 08:22:14 Prime com.ubuntu.SoftwareProperties[1303]:   File "/usr/lib/software-properties/software-properties-dbus", line 68, in <module>
Oct 04 08:22:14 Prime com.ubuntu.SoftwareProperties[1303]:     server = SoftwarePropertiesDBus(bus, datadir=datadir)
Oct 04 08:22:14 Prime com.ubuntu.SoftwareProperties[1303]:   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/softwareproperties/dbus/SoftwarePropertiesDBus.py", line 66, in __init__
Oct 04 08:22:14 Prime com.ubuntu.SoftwareProperties[1303]:     self._livepatch_service = LivepatchService()
Oct 04 08:22:14 Prime com.ubuntu.SoftwareProperties[1303]:   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/softwareproperties/LivepatchService.py", line 93, in __init__
Oct 04 08:22:14 Prime com.ubuntu.SoftwareProperties[1303]:     self._session = requests_unixsocket.Session()
Oct 04 08:22:14 Prime com.ubuntu.SoftwareProperties[1303]: NameError: name 'requests_unixsocket' is not defined
```

Also, the python package 'requests_unixsocket' is installed in the system(see below). Hence I don't understand the error msg `NameError: name 'requests_unixsocket' is not defined`:

```
$ pip list | grep requests
requests                2.24.0
requests-unixsocket     0.1.5
WARNING: You are using pip version 20.2.2; however, version 20.2.3 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the '/usr/bin/python3 -m pip install --upgrade pip' command.
$ pip3 list | grep requests
requests                2.24.0
requests-unixsocket     0.1.5
WARNING: You are using pip version 20.2.2; however, version 20.2.3 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the '/usr/bin/python3 -m pip install --upgrade pip' command.
$ pip3 list --user | grep requests
requests            2.24.0
WARNING: You are using pip version 20.2.2; however, version 20.2.3 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the '/usr/bin/python3 -m pip install --upgrade pip' command.
```

I have tried to import requests_unixsocket explicitly. It works. See below.

```
Python 3.6.9 (default, Jul 17 2020, 12:50:27) 
[GCC 8.4.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license()" for more information.
>>> import requests_unixsocket
>>> a = requests_unixsocket.Session()
>>> a
<requests_unixsocket.Session object at 0x7fb103952470>
```

I don't understand why I can import the package but `/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/softwareproperties/LivepatchService.py` can't see it. It does exist:

```
$ ls /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/ | grep request
requests_unixsocket
requests_unixsocket-0.1.5.egg-info
```

Comment: Provide information on the desktop you use. Terminal command is `software-properties-gtk`

Comment: @vanadium I had updated my question with the info you ad asked.

Comment: @vanadium I found a similar question on my issue [here](https://askubuntu.com/q/1171211/541417). The 2 answers posted there could not solve my issue.

Comment: Did you do something to your system's python installation?

Comment: @OrganicMarble The closest activity I can recall was upgrading pip3 packages. Specifically, I mentioned this in Update1. If there is an issue with my system's Python installation, is there any way to fix it? Or is the brokeness irreparable and I have to reinstall Ubuntu 18.04?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I am on Ubuntu 20.04 and I experienced this problem. I tried the posts that recommended reinstalling `python3-six` and `python3-certifi`, but those didn't work for me.  However, `software-properties-gtk` did start working again for me after I reinstalled `python3-requests` and `python3-idna`.  So, to sum up the commands I ran:

```
sudo apt install --reinstall python3-six python3-certifi python3-requests python3-idna
sudo apt install --reinstall software-properties-gtk
software-properties-gtk
```

and I was back in business.

Comment: Worked after correcting the typo in your command first line. It should be `sudo apt install --reinstall python3-six python3-certifi python3-requests python3-idna`.  I have made the edit. Pls accept it. :)

Comment: I experienced this problem on Ubuntu 20.04 too. I reinstalled all `python3-six`, `python3-certifi`, `python3-requests`, `python3-idna`, `python3-chardet`, `python3-urllib3` and `software-properties-gtk` but didn't work for me. Finally I tried `software-properties-qt` and worked for me (`sudo apt install software-properties-qt`). In appearance and performance it is almost like `software-properties-gtk`.

Comment: Thanks, worked for me too! (ubuntu 20.04)

Comment: None of these solutions worked for me. What worked, amazingly, was directly modifying the affected Python code, saving it, testing it (which worked), and then *undoing* the changes, after which `software-properties-gtk` *still* worked. Very strange. See https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/software-properties/+bug/1830914/comments/14

Answer (score 2):

Same problem on Ubuntu 20.10... I had a look to dbus messages:

```
sudo systemctl status dbus.service
```

and saw this line:

```
.../... com.ubuntu.SoftwareProperties[8310]: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'chardet'
```

So I reinstalled chardet:

```
sudo apt install --reinstall python3-chardet
```

and `software-properties-gtk` is back.

The log shows:

```
dbus-daemon[1130]: [system] Successfully activated service 'com.ubuntu.SoftwareProperties'
```

Hope it helps.