# GLib-GIO-ERROR Settings schema 'com.ubuntu.SoftwareProperties' does not contain a key named 'ubuntu-pro-banner-visible'

Tags: gnome, software-center, gtk

I was trying to clean up old repositories in my system (20.04.4) in order to finally get read of the errors about old repos not having release files.

I discovered that when using Synaptic that I couldn't open the repositories option from the Settings menu. If I try to open Software Properties from the terminal using "software-properties-gtk" I get the following error:

> (software-properties-gtk:21925): GLib-GIO-ERROR **: 22:43:26.896: Settings schema 'com.ubuntu.SoftwareProperties' does not contain a key named 'ubuntu-pro-banner-visible'
> Trace/breakpoint trap (core dumped)"

However, when I open /usr/share/glib-2.0/schemas/com.ubuntu.SoftwareProperties.gschema.xml in Gedit, the key does appear and seems to be formatted correctly.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<schemalist>
    <schema id="com.ubuntu.SoftwareProperties" path="/com/ubuntu/SoftwareProperties/">
        <key name="goa-account-id" type="s">
            <default>""</default>
            <summary>Livepatch account id</summary>
            <description>gnome-online-account account id used for livepatch authentication.</description>
        </key>
        <key name="ubuntu-pro-banner-visible" type="b">
            <default>true</default>
            <summary>Ubuntu Pro banner visibility</summary>
            <description>True if the Ubuntu Pro banner should be shown.</description>
        </key>
    </schema>
</schemalist>
```

All I have done so far to attempt a repair is to reinstall software-properties-common and software-properties-gtk.

Answer (score 0):

The solution I ended up using

Reading this answer https://askubuntu.com/a/1312345/656062 I noticed a comment mentioning `software-properties-qt` which should be almost the same as `software-properties-gtk`.

I installed it with `sudo apt install software-properties-qt` and it works without problems, so maybe that could be an alternative for people who can't get the gtk version to work.