# ubuntu 18.04 software-properties-gtk failing

Tags: 18.04, update-manager, additional-drivers

ubuntu 18.04 software-properties-gtk failing when I try to open the software&update it doesn't open and when I tried to `sudo software-properties-gtk`

it return this error

```
ERROR:dbus.proxies:Introspect error on :1.136:/: dbus.exceptions.DBusException: org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.NoReply: Message recipient disconnected from message bus without replying
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/software-properties-gtk", line 100, in <module>
    app = SoftwarePropertiesGtk(datadir=options.data_dir, options=options, file=file)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/softwareproperties/gtk/SoftwarePropertiesGtk.py", line 173, in __init__
    self.backend.Reload();
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/dbus/proxies.py", line 70, in __call__
    return self._proxy_method(*args, **keywords)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/dbus/proxies.py", line 145, in __call__
    **keywords)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/dbus/connection.py", line 651, in call_blocking
    message, timeout)
dbus.exceptions.DBusException: org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.ServiceUnknown: The name :1.136 was not provided by any .service files
```

I tried to reinstall **software-properties-gtk** but it didn't work
I also tried to reinstall python-six packages as recommended by other blogs but also didn't solve my issue.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ubuntu 18.04 software-properties-gtk failing with org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.ServiceUnknown](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1171211/ubuntu-18-04-software-properties-gtk-failing-with-org-freedesktop-dbus-error-ser)

Comment: No, I already tried the solution proposed but It didn't help me to solve my problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following

```
sudo apt reinstall python3-six python3-certifi
```

I had months suffering from this issue on both `18.04` and `20.04`. I came by this answer on one of the forums and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Probably the same issue and the solution is shared [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1171211/ubuntu-18-04-software-properties-gtk-failing-with-org-freedesktop-dbus-error-ser)

According to Tim Richardson:

> The package python3-six was installed (so my package manager said).
> when I reinstalled this package, software-properties-gtk worked again.

You may try to install python-six package and reinstall software-properties-gtk aftermath.

```
sudo apt install python-six
```

Or you may want to install it via pip

```
pip install six
```

After you installed python-six package, reinstall the software-properties-gtk like

```
sudo apt install --reinstall software-properties-gtk
```

Hope it solves your problem.