# software & update app not opening

Tags: 18.04, software-center

After `installing` Python3.7, the `software-properties-gtk` is not opening. When calling it from terminal, the following error is shown:

```
ERROR:dbus.proxies:Introspect error on :1.171:/: dbus.exceptions.DBusException: org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.NoReply: Message recipient disconnected from message bus without replying
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/software-properties-gtk", line 100, in <module>
    app = SoftwarePropertiesGtk(datadir=options.data_dir, options=options, file=file)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/softwareproperties/gtk/SoftwarePropertiesGtk.py", line 173, in __init__
    self.backend.Reload();
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/dbus/proxies.py", line 70, in __call__
    return self._proxy_method(*args, **keywords)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/dbus/proxies.py", line 145, in __call__
    **keywords)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/dbus/connection.py", line 651, in call_blocking
    message, timeout)
dbus.exceptions.DBusException: org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.ServiceUnknown: The name :1.171 was not provided by any .service files
```

I am running `UBUNTU 18.04`. I [checked this post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1171211/ubuntu-18-04-software-properties-gtk-failing-with-org-freedesktop-dbus-error-ser), but all answers were not working. I hope someone came by this problem and was able to solve it. Thanks

Edit:
Upon request, here is the command output:

```
#which python; ls -l $(which python); echo =; which python3; ls -l $(which python3)

/usr/bin/python
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 24 Nov  4 20:51 /usr/bin/python -> /etc/alternatives/python
=
/usr/bin/python3
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 25 Nov  4 20:54 /usr/bin/python3 -> /etc/alternatives/python3
```

**Another debugging request**

```
#ls -al /usr/bin/ | grep python

lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root           26 Mar 26  2018 dh_pypy -> ../share/dh-python/dh_pypy
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root root         1056 Apr 16  2018 dh_python2
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root           29 Mar 26  2018 dh_python3 -> ../share/dh-python/dh_python3
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root           23 Sep 30 15:38 pdb2.7 -> ../lib/python2.7/pdb.py
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root           23 Oct  8 14:12 pdb3.6 -> ../lib/python3.6/pdb.py
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root           23 Aug 18 08:22 pdb3.7 -> ../lib/python3.7/pdb.py
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root           31 Oct 25  2018 py3versions -> ../share/python3/py3versions.py
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root           26 Mar 26  2018 pybuild -> ../share/dh-python/pybuild
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root            9 Apr 16  2018 python -> python2.7
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root            9 Apr 16  2018 python2 -> python2.7
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root root      3628976 Sep 30 15:38 python2.7
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root           25 Nov  6 13:38 python3 -> /etc/alternatives/python3
-rwxr-xr-x  2 root root      4526456 Oct  8 14:12 python3.6
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root           33 Oct  8 14:12 python3.6-config -> x86_64-linux-gnu-python3.6-config
-rwxr-xr-x  2 root root      4526456 Oct  8 14:12 python3.6m
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root           34 Oct  8 14:12 python3.6m-config -> x86_64-linux-gnu-python3.6m-config
-rwxr-xr-x  2 root root      5316432 Aug 18 08:22 python3.7
-rwxr-xr-x  2 root root      5316432 Aug 18 08:22 python3.7m
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root           16 Oct 25  2018 python3-config -> python3.6-config
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root           10 Oct 25  2018 python3m -> python3.6m
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root           17 Oct 25  2018 python3m-config -> python3.6m-config
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root           29 Apr 16  2018 pyversions -> ../share/python/pyversions.py
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root           34 Oct  8 14:12 x86_64-linux-gnu-python3.6-config -> x86_64-linux-gnu-python3.6m-config
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root root         3283 Oct  8 14:12 x86_64-linux-gnu-python3.6m-config
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root           33 Oct 25  2018 x86_64-linux-gnu-python3-config -> x86_64-linux-gnu-python3.6-config
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root           34 Oct 25  2018 x86_64-linux-gnu-python3m-config -> x86_64-linux-gnu-python3.6m-config

#readlink -f /usr/bin/python 

/usr/bin/python2.7

#ls -al /usr/bin/ | grep python3

lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root           29 Mar 26  2018 dh_python3 -> ../share/dh-python/dh_python3
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root           23 Oct  8 14:12 pdb3.6 -> ../lib/python3.6/pdb.py
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root           23 Aug 18 08:22 pdb3.7 -> ../lib/python3.7/pdb.py
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root           31 Oct 25  2018 py3versions -> ../share/python3/py3versions.py
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root           25 Nov  6 13:38 python3 -> /etc/alternatives/python3
-rwxr-xr-x  2 root root      4526456 Oct  8 14:12 python3.6
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root           33 Oct  8 14:12 python3.6-config -> x86_64-linux-gnu-python3.6-config
-rwxr-xr-x  2 root root      4526456 Oct  8 14:12 python3.6m
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root           34 Oct  8 14:12 python3.6m-config -> x86_64-linux-gnu-python3.6m-config
-rwxr-xr-x  2 root root      5316432 Aug 18 08:22 python3.7
-rwxr-xr-x  2 root root      5316432 Aug 18 08:22 python3.7m
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root           16 Oct 25  2018 python3-config -> python3.6-config
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root           10 Oct 25  2018 python3m -> python3.6m
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root           17 Oct 25  2018 python3m-config -> python3.6m-config
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root           34 Oct  8 14:12 x86_64-linux-gnu-python3.6-config -> x86_64-linux-gnu-python3.6m-config
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root root         3283 Oct  8 14:12 x86_64-linux-gnu-python3.6m-config
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root           33 Oct 25  2018 x86_64-linux-gnu-python3-config -> x86_64-linux-gnu-python3.6-config
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root           34 Oct 25  2018 x86_64-linux-gnu-python3m-config -> x86_64-linux-gnu-python3.6m-config
```

**DBUS service check**

```
#systemctl status dbus.service

● dbus.service - D-Bus System Message Bus
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/dbus.service; static; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (running) since Sun 2020-11-08 12:40:49 EET; 1h 22min ago
     Docs: man:dbus-daemon(1)
 Main PID: 763 (dbus-daemon)
    Tasks: 3 (limit: 4915)
   CGroup: /system.slice/dbus.service
           ├─  763 /usr/bin/dbus-daemon --system --address=systemd: --nofork --nopidfile --systemd-activation --syslog-only
           └─13887 /usr/bin/python3 /usr/share/usb-creator/usb-creator-helper

Nov 08 13:51:00 TTS-UBUNTU dbus-daemon[763]: [system] Activating via systemd: service name='org.freedesktop.hostname1' unit='dbus-org.freedesktop.hostname1.service'
Nov 08 13:51:00 TTS-UBUNTU dbus-daemon[763]: [system] Successfully activated service 'org.freedesktop.hostname1'
Nov 08 13:52:18 TTS-UBUNTU dbus-daemon[763]: [system] Activating via systemd: service name='org.freedesktop.hostname1' unit='dbus-org.freedesktop.hostname1.service'
Nov 08 13:52:18 TTS-UBUNTU dbus-daemon[763]: [system] Successfully activated service 'org.freedesktop.hostname1'
Nov 08 13:52:58 TTS-UBUNTU dbus-daemon[763]: [system] Activating via systemd: service name='org.freedesktop.hostname1' unit='dbus-org.freedesktop.hostname1.service'
Nov 08 13:52:58 TTS-UBUNTU dbus-daemon[763]: [system] Successfully activated service 'org.freedesktop.hostname1'
Nov 08 13:57:39 TTS-UBUNTU dbus-daemon[763]: [system] Activating via systemd: service name='org.freedesktop.hostname1' unit='dbus-org.freedesktop.hostname1.service'
Nov 08 13:57:39 TTS-UBUNTU dbus-daemon[763]: [system] Successfully activated service 'org.freedesktop.hostname1'
Nov 08 13:58:19 TTS-UBUNTU dbus-daemon[763]: [system] Activating via systemd: service name='org.freedesktop.hostname1' unit='dbus-org.freedesktop.hostname1.service'
Nov 08 13:58:19 TTS-UBUNTU dbus-daemon[763]: [system] Successfully activated service 'org.freedesktop.hostname1'
```

Comment: What do you mean by "After using Python3.7"?

Comment: Appears that some python core files are missing.  Have you tried uninstalling and then installing python again.  This hopefully should resolve the problem.

Comment: @aneesh_nair I don't think it's safe to uninstall Python since many packages will depend on it. It can mess up the system.

Comment: @schrodigerscatcuriosity , installing it is what I meant

Comment: @technastic_tc I agree with you. It ended up before with fresh installation. It seems that having Python 3.7 is making an issue although python 3.6 is still the default.

Comment: @wbadry, Would you add the output of `which python; ls -l $(which python); echo =; which python3; ls -l $(which python3)`

Comment: @wbadry What are the steps you followed to install Python 3.7? Did you follow instructions from any website? If yes, please do share the link of the website.

Comment: another python crasher.

Comment: @user.dz I updated the post with the command output

Comment: `ls -al /usr/bin/ | grep python` and `readlink -f /usr/bin/python` and `/usr/bin/ | grep python3`

Comment: @nobody updated the post with requested commands

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
sudo update-alternatives  --remove-all python3
```

from manpage

> Remove all alternatives and all of their associated slave links.  name
> is a name in the alternatives directory (in your case python3)

```
sudo rm /usr/bin/python3
```

Then create a new link.

```
sudo ln -s /usr/bin/python3.6  /usr/bin/python3
```

Comment: Thanks. I did the exact steps. The problem still exists.

Comment: Bäh,  `systemctl status dbus.service`  please.

Comment: the post was updated.

Comment: I'm sorry I running out of ideas. Something installed with python-pip or python3-pip?

Comment: Thanks @nobody. After an update today, it was fixed. I believe it was a bug and the UBUNTU team fixed it. Thank you so much for your time taken to solve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

I also had the same problem.
I did `sudo update-alternatives --config python3` and switched to `python 3.6`:

[image: python version change]

Good luck !!!

Comment: python2 and python3 normally not configured over alternativen system. Easiest way is to remove the distorbing python3.7 package.

Comment: Thank but the problem is still existing as python3 is already set as default for Python3